Citation hunting: Floer on spectral sequences
I vaguely remember a YouTube talk that began with a citation from Floer regarding the existence of a spectral sequence. The idea was that given a manifold with a Morse function, we can construct a spectral sequence where the first page is the direct sum of critical points. The differentials on the
-th page are derived from the moduli spaces of flow lines.
I also found this idea in Ralph Cohen's paper, "The Floer homotopy type of the cotangent bundle", but I am looking for Floer's original reference.
Can anyone identify which paper by Floer discusses this? Alternatively, does anyone know the exact citation?.

After searching google scholar among published papers of Floer, there seems to exist only one text where spectral sequences are mentioned at all (except the passing mention of Leray s.s.):
Witten's complex and infinite-dimensional Morse theory, J. Differential Geom. 30(1): 207-221 (1989).
Here is the relevant remark (on p. 213):

